# Career search url shows specific user

Tags: support, jobs, search

If I go to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/search` it shows a certain user. Is there any specific reason for it?

*Update:*

Since the link is now giving a 404, adding a screenshot using [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:G_9Wmp4h0FoJ:careers.stackoverflow.com/search):

> [image]

Comment: There is simply no global search functionality on Careers, you can search Jobs or Companies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a Careers user chose an alias called `search` (sure he had done this for the reason to be run into this way ;). It's not a search page.

> [image]

(So it's no more weird than, say, http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jeff)

The search, in the term of searching, is still there. You can search for jobs as seen on the main page. E.g. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=Unicorns

Comment: But I see Page Not Found. Did the user change his/her privacy settings in the last 40 minutes?

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is indeed giving a 404 now. Did the user change it or SE devs/CMs?

Comment: @Aziz can't really know, but likely the team figured such an alias isn't valid and nuked it.